# Receiving callback from adapter to Fragment

Tags: java, android, interface

I want to return a **callback from a custom adapter to my fragment**. However the adapter won't let me pass the reference of the Fragment implementing the interface defined in custom adapter. How can I receive callbacks from adapter to fragment?

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment implements MyInterface
{
 @Override
 public void onCreateView()
 {
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this); // error here: How to resolve
 }

 @Override
 public void mySignal()
 {
 }
}


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerViewAdapter
{
   MyInterface listener;

   public MyAdapter(MyInterface listener)
   {
      this.listener = listener;
   }


  public interface MyInterface
  {
     public void mySignal();
  }

}
```

Comment: What means XXXX error here?

Comment: XXXX is not a very clear error, what error are you actually getting?

Comment: It was nothing just an indication for you readers

Comment: you can access fragment to activity and activity to fragment.

Annnd you can access activity from adapter, so, line is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a clear definition and SOC you could try this instead,

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment 
{
 @Override
 public void onCreateView()
 {

   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new MyInterface() {
             @Override
             public void mySignal()
             {
                    //do stuff here
             }
    }); 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Fragment has this method

`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Sorry for my question! What is onCreateView() method without any params?

This way will work fine if there is not any different things more.